# Not sure how to merge data based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

df1:

```
tID  sID  dID  date1 date2
1234 4321 5432 7/12  8/13
7890 5688 4567 8/21  9/30
```

df2:

```
sID  dID  date3 
4321 5432 7/20
5688 4567 9/15
```

I'd like to assign append a `tID` to `df2` if:

- `date3` is between `date1` and `date2`
- the `sID` are the same
- the `dID` are the same

df3:

```
tID  sID  dID  date3 
1234 4321 5432 7/20
7890 5688 4567 9/15
```

My first thought was to loop through both dataframes and use `if` statements but that really doesn't seem like an efficient approach.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: is df2 dID `8/21` a typo? Or is the ID meant to be a date there?
Also do all 3 conditions have to be satisfied or just one?

Comment: yes, sorry! updated

Comment: @madsthaks you didn't update `df3`. Also, you didn't answer the question about conditions.

Comment: @DennisGolomazov Gonna take a wild guess here, since it seems the sID of the second row doesn't match. Could also be a typo tho, perhaps that row got shifted to the left somehow?

Comment: @DennisGolomazov, I apologize, ended up getting formatted incorrectly. Should be better now.

Comment: @madsthaks ok, let me ask again. In this sentence: `I'd like to assign append a tID to df2 if:`, do you want ALL 3 conditions to be satisfied, or only 1 is enough?

Comment: All 3 need to be satisfied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, first set them to the same index (as `str`, if the IDs might contain ids such as `8/21` before the edit. If all ids are ints, no need to do the `astype` steps)

```
df['sID'] = df.sID.astype(str)
df['dID'] = df.dID.astype(str)
df = df.set_index(['sID', 'dID'])


df2['sID'] = df2.sID.astype(str)
df2['dID'] = df2.dID.astype(str)
df2 = df2.set_index(['sID', 'dID'])
```

Then filter and assign using `loc`

```
m = df2.index.isin(df.index)
sub = df.loc[df2[m].date3.index]
s = df2[m].date3.between(sub.date1, sub.date2)
df2.loc[:, 'tID'] = df.loc[s[s].index, 'tID']
```

Outputs

```
                date3   tID
sID dID     
4321    5432    7/20    1234
5688    4567    9/15    7890
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['sID', 'dID'])
print df3[df3.date3.between(df3.date1, df3.date2)].drop(['date1', 'date2'], axis=1)

    tID   sID   dID date3
0  1234  4321  5432  7/20
1  7890  5688  4567  9/15
```

Thanks @RafaelC for the `between` idea.